# Convert money datatype to 3 decimal places

Tags: sql-server, decimal, type-conversion, currency

I am trying to show my `PT.TotalAmount`(money) field in decimal format upto 3 decimal places. I tried using

```
CAST(ROUND(123.4567, 3) AS MONEY)
```

But I get error:

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO
>   statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look
>   for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed.
>   Change the alias to a valid name.

Here is my SP:

```
Select PT.[ID] 'TransactionID', PT.BatchNumber, PT.SequenceNumber, PT.TransactionDate,   
 PT.TerminalID ,CAST(ROUND(PT.TotalAmount, 2) AS MONEY), PT.TransactionTypeID, TT.TransactionType,     
 PT.PAN 'EmbossLine',PT.PreBalanceAmount, PT.PostBalanceAmount, RefTxnID,   
SettlementDate,PaidCash, CreditAmount, DiscountAmount,    
RefPAN, PT.Remarks, '&nbsp; ' + CashierCard as 'SupervisorCard',St.StoreID    
into #Temp    
from POS_Transactions PT inner join TransactionType TT on TT.TransactionTypeID = PT.TransactionTypeID     
inner join Staff St on St.CardNumber=PT.CashierCard     
where     
PT.[ID] not in (Select distinct isnull(TransactionID,0) from Testcards)    
and (PT.TransactionDate >= @DateFrom)    
and (PT.TransactionDate < @DateTo)    
and (PT.TransactionTypeID = @TransactionTypeID or @TransactionTypeID = -999)    



select T.*, '&nbsp; '+  C.EmbossLine as 'EmbossLine', '&nbsp;'+ C.EmbossLine as 'EmbossLine1',    

isnull(C.FirstName,'') +' '+ isnull(C.LastName,'') 'EmbossName',C.FirstName,C.LastName,City.CityName,Country.CountryName,Country.CurrencyName,  PM.MerchantID , PM.MerchantName1, C.AccountNumber, C.VehicleNumber    

from #Temp T     

inner join Card C on C.EmbossLine= T.EmbossLine    

inner join Terminal on Terminal.TerminalID = T.TerminalID    

inner join Merchant PM on  PM.MerchantID = Terminal.MerchantID    

inner join City on City.CityID = PM.CityID    

inner join Country on Country.CountryID = PM.CountryID     

where C.Status <>'E3'    

and C.CardID not in (Select distinct isnull(CardID,0) from Testcards)    

and (PM.MerchantID =@MerchantID or @MerchantID='-999')    

and (C.EmbossLine like '%'+@EmbossLine+'%' or @EmbossLine like '-999')    

and (C.FirstName like '%'+@FirstName+'%' or @FirstName like '-999')    

and (C.LastName like '%'+@LastName+'%' or @LastName like '-999')    

and (PM.CountryID = @CountryID or @CountryID ='-999')    

and(PM.CityID = @CityID or @CityID ='-999')    

order by T.TransactionDate, MerchantName1, T.BatchNumber, T.SequenceNumber    

drop table #Temp
```

Why am I getting this error? Whats wrong in conversion? When I simply write `PT.TotalAmount` in my `Select` statement, the query is completed successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add any alias name for `CAST(ROUND(PT.TotalAmount, 2) AS MONEY)` as `roundedamont(whatever column name you want)` in your sql query.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question; It still shows values upto 4 decimal places. Why? Do I need to make conversions in my `VB` code for it to display upto 3 decimal places?

Comment: I used in SQL server 2008 R2 and it works(means it shows only 3 decimal value)

Answer (score 0):

**Select * into statement require each column have distinct name**

```
Select PT.[ID] 'TransactionID', PT.BatchNumber, PT.SequenceNumber, PT.TransactionDate,   
 PT.TerminalID ,CAST(ROUND(PT.TotalAmount, 2) AS MONEY)<----Give Alias HERE
```